# Rails 3 - Multi-form Wizard - Trying to edit record does not save values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am doing a multi-form wizard, following the steps provide by [Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms). Creating a new record works, so I was trying to use the same logic for when I edit a record. However, the values that I change do not change -- when I edit something from the first form, go forward then backwards, my edits do not save. Here is the code in my controller:

```
  def edit
    session[:edit] = "Only change the fields you wish to edit"
    @demographic = Demographic.find(params[:id])
    session[:demographic_params] ||= {}  
  end

  def update
    session[:demographic_params].deep_merge!(params[:demographic]) if params[:demographic]  
    @demographic = Demographic.find(params[:id])
    @demographic.current_step = session[:demographic_step]
    if params[:back_button]
      @demographic.previous_step
    elsif @demographic.last_step?
      @demographic.update_attributes(params[:demographic])
      updated = true 
    else
      @demographic.next_step
    end    
    session[:demographic_step] = @demographic.current_step
    if not updated
      render "edit"
    else
      session[:demographic_params] = session[:demographic_step] = nil
      flash[:notice] = "Entry entered successfully"
      redirect_to demographic_path
    end
  end
```

What should I change that allows for saving the edits?

Comment: Ever figure out how to save it on every step?

Comment: @ZMorek sorry for the late response, but yes I did what Gabriel did and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will work, but I think that should be something like this to save on every "step change":

```
  def update
    session[:demographic_params].deep_merge!(params[:demographic]) if params[:demographic]  
    @demographic = Demographic.find(params[:id])
    @demographic.current_step = session[:demographic_step]
    @demographic.update_attributes(params[:demographic])
    if params[:back_button]
      @demographic.previous_step
    elsif @demographic.last_step?
      updated = true 
    else
      @demographic.next_step
    end    
    session[:demographic_step] = @demographic.current_step
    if not updated
      render "edit"
    else
      session[:demographic_params] = session[:demographic_step] = nil
      flash[:notice] = "Entry entered successfully"
      redirect_to demographic_path
    end
  end
```

I.e., move the `@demographic.update_attributes` outsite the "step-by-step" logic.

So, I think that you should walk this way to solve your problem.

Hope this helps.